# How to swap SetDelayed expressions?

Tags: core-language

Suppose, there are two delayed expressions

```
D1:= RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-1, 0}]];
D2:= RandomVariate[ UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
```

`D1, D2` work as needed generating a pair of random numbers. How to swap `D1, D2` without repeating the full coding

```
D2:= RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-1, 0}]];
D1:= RandomVariate[ UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
```

Clearly, that code `{D1,D2}= (or :=) {D2,D1}` does not work.

Answer (score 6):

There are different usages of `SetDelayed`. Read `SetDelayed` [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html), Section  `Scope` > `Diffrent Kinds of Values` for more information.

This solution works on `var := def` (like your case) not `var[] := def` or other kinds.

### Code

```
ClearAll[swapSetDelays];

SetAttributes[swapSetDelays, HoldAll];

swapSetDelays[a_, b_] := With[{temp = OwnValues[a]},
  OwnValues[a] = OwnValues[b] /. HoldPattern[b] :> a;
  OwnValues[b] = temp /. HoldPattern[a] :> b;
  ]
```

### Example

```
SeedRandom[1];

r1 := RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
r2 := RandomInteger[{11, 20}];

{r1, r2}
(* Out: {2,15} *)

swapSetDelays[r1, r2];

{r1, r2}
(* Out: {11, 8} *)
```

Comment: +1 (but strictly, more clever than useful)

Comment: @mikado thanks for your feedback but I should confess that the idea came from `OwnValues` Neat Examples .

Comment: This works fine
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In the rather unlikely case of you actually wanting to swap two definitions, e.g.

```
D1 := RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-1, 0}]];
D2 := RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
```

You can do so temporarily

```
Module[{D1 = D2, D2 = D1}, Print[{D1, D2}]]
{0.863742,-0.710931}
```

If you've already used these definitions e.g.

```
print := Print[{D1, D2}]
print
{-0.349444,0.720738}
```

and would like to interchange them temporarily, you can use

```
Block[{D1 = D2, D2 = D1}, print]
{0.123198,-0.592611}
```

Needless to say, if you interchange them permanently, there is risk of becoming confused about how many times you've done it!

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just define a single function?

```
d[x_,y_]:=RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{x, y}]];
```

Then call it as:

```
D1 = d[-1,0]
```

or

```
D2 = d[0,1]
```

Comment: Yeah, this possible, but not very fit to my purpose